# Cannot extract default values for json object using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, forms

I'm trying to use ajax to validate a simple form but i'm using 3 parts. front side.html, back side.php, and main javascript.js. I'm also using a pseudo server. the problem lies here.

```
$("#InsertDefault").click(function()
{ $.ajax("backend.php?act=default", { success: function(result){
console.log($.parseJSON(result))
data = $.parseJSON(result);
document.getElementById("name").value = data["name"]
},
error: document.getElementById("errors").innerHTML  = "<li>It didn't work...  </li>"      
}); // ajax close
}); //click close
```

When i call ajax, i want to enter backend.php and also set the parameter "act" to default.

```
// Return JSON default data if requested
if ($_REQUEST['act'] == 'default'){
$defaultData = array('name' => "Jane", 'postal' => "L5B4G6", 'phone' => "9055751212",'address' => "135 Fennel Street");
echo json_encode($defaultData);
}
```

if this works, i have a success option to the ajax call that takes "result" (the default values as a string) and parse it to JSON making an object called data. When i take the name from data which should be "Jane" by default and put it in the value field for my text field

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
```

It should populate it with the name Jane, but instead it fails and does my error option "It didn't work" Have a made a mistake or failed to add something?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.` to access anything from array in javascript,

co

change

```
document.getElementById("name").value = data["name"]// this is in php
```

to

```
var data = $.parseJSON(result);
alert(data.name)
document.getElementById("name").value = data.name
                                             ^
data.name;// for name,
data.postal;// for postal code
..// so on
```

Comment: this gave me a bit of hope as the console printed the default json object! but it stopped working for some reason and I wasn't able to extract the name...

Answer (score 0):

Thing you are missing `header('Content-type: application/json');` before the echo in php part. Currently ajax things it gets plain text instead of json response.

Comment: I tried adding that line inside but it didn't seem to help change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Fix your ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url:"backend.php?act=default",
success: function(result){
  $("#name").val(result.name);
}});
```

use the header `header('Content-type: application/json');` in backend.php

Comment: although much more appealing, i ran into new errors replacing your code, something about unknown identifiers